# Laravel 7 extract css / js from included layout or component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying build website using Laravel 7 but I stack on extracting JS or CSS from partial layouts to the main layout. My `app.blade.php` layout should be built from smaller pieces like a slider. My main problem is I cannot to attach specific CSS to `<head>` or slider `js` to bottom of the page. It works for `@extends()`, but in this case, I want to use `@inclide` or `<x-component/>`. The slider is more static but wants to reuse this code in some places. I also tried `@push` and `@stack` but still cannot do it till layout do not extend `app.layout`

```php
<head>
    @yield('css')

</head>
<body>

<x-test></x-test>

@include('layouts.navbar')
@include('layouts.slider') <-slider js

@yield('content')

@yield('js')

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have pointed to the wrong layout. If I use @stack/@pull or @yield/@section from child layout (this with @extend('layout.app') ) then all works fine.Also, It renders top and bottom sections.

Example:

app.blade.php

```
<head>
    @yield('css')
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@include('layouts.test')
```

test.blade.php

```
@push('xxx2')
    text
@endpush


@section('css')
    css
@endsection
```